# Privacy loss in Provenance Corda

Tags: corda

In a closed loop network, when parties transfer assets, the transactions associated with that are also shared. So the otherparty would get to know everything about my past transactions with that asset especially in the case of cash or securities. This actually is a privacy concern. Also, since it is a private network, after few years everyone in the network might get know the past transactions(most if not all) of every other node based on their interaction.

How this issue handled or is there a workaround for this?
How do you compare this aspect of privacy with other platforms?

Answer (score 3):

A number of techniques to address these privacy concerns are discussed in section 15 of the Corda [technical whitepaper](https://docs.corda.net/_static/corda-technical-whitepaper.pdf), namely:

- Transaction tear-offs
- Confidential public keys
- Graph pruning
- Secure hardware
- Mix networks
- Zero knowledge proofs

Of these, transaction tear-offs are already implemented and used for cases such as notarisation and oracles. However, in their current form, they do not address the issue of finding out data via transaction resolution.

Confidential public keys are also already implemented. They allow one-time keys to be used for each transaction, so that transactions can't be correlated based on the keys used. This means that you can verify a chain of transactions without knowing the identities of the parties involved in the chain.

Graph pruning, or "chain snipping" as it's sometimes known, is already supported, and is used in some of the R3 members' projects. A trusted central party (e.g. the issuer of a currency) will re-issue the assets in a non-atomic way to shorten the transaction chain.

A secure hardware privacy layer is being implemented in the form of SGX as well. R3 has an agreement with Intel to use their enclaves. The current plan is for transaction resolution to occur within software enclaves, so that no data at all is seen by the user during transaction resolution.

My understanding is that zero knowledge proofs are still too slow to be feasible for the complex transaction used by Corda, but they may become a feasible technique in the future. I am not aware of any usage of mix networks for privacy.

One of the benefits of Corda's architecture is that these privacy techniques can be layered on top of each other. For example, key randomisation, graph pruning and secure hardware techniques are compatible and can all be used simultaneously to achieve greater privacy.

Comment: As such... Corda is the only platform that can provide complete transaction confidentiality at scale.

Comment: Agree, key randomisation is actually enough to answer the OP's question. In short, it means that every party may use a new random key per transaction and there is no way to link these keys with the real entity when you receive the older transactions. Practically, transacting parties exchange signatures over the new random keys (so they have a proof if requested by a regulator at a later time and for their records), but these signatures are not sent as part of the state chain. All in all, when you receive older transactions you just see random keys.

Comment: I don't think key randomisation is the full answer. Since Corda handles all types of assets, you can imagine that for certain asset types, deductions could be made about who owned what and when, even if the identities are anonymous. That's why it's god to not just rely on a single confidentiality solution IMO.

Comment: Well, the question focuses on older transactions and it doesn't make any references on the notary side (where eg secure enclaves would provide an extra degree of privacy). On the other hand, pruning reduces the problem to a smaller one (it depends a lot on the policy on how often to apply), but again, key randomisation remains the basis of privacy preserving and the rest of the methods build upon it.

Comment: @joel "deductions could be made about who owned what and when"

Why this cannot be obfuscated (if required) by forcibly creating extra transactions and send the assets to new randomised keys that you own? This is generally a good practice to make things more complicated to trace, especially if there are no (or negligible) fees per tx.

Comment: It depends on the thing being modelled IMO. Imagine a state that models who holds a given piece of property. Even with key randomisation, you could imagine that combining knowledge of the transactions with real-world knowledge could allow you to determine who is involved.

Answer (score 1):

There are blog posts about our work with SGX here:

https://www.corda.net/2017/06/corda-sgx-privacy-update/

https://www.corda.net/2017/08/sgx-corda-film/

SGX enables transaction dependencies to be encrypted. It's not available yet, but we've done some development work on this project already.