# Transaction privacy on corda M14

Tags: privacy, corda

In demobench release M14, I did the following:

1. Bank of Breakfast Tea self issued cash worth 100 USD
2. Bank of Breakfast Tea pays 30 USD to Bank of Big Apples
3. Bank of Breakfast Tea pays 10 USD to Bank of Baguettes

The explorer of Bank of Baguettes after step #3, shows that #2 happened. This implies that if any participant receives any fungible assets, then the participant knows all the history of the asset from issuance of the asset. In the above example is there any way so that Bank of Breakfast Tea  and Bank of Big Apples hides their identity, amount from Bank of Baguettes? Clearly it is a privacy issue wrt Bank of Breakfast Tea  and Bank of Big Apples.

I will be interested to know how can I use **Key randomisation**  or **Transaction tear-offs** as mentioned in the url [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710036/privacy-loss-in-provenance-corda) at M14 release to address the above issue ? Any sample example available?

Also if a fungible asset is traded multiple times ( say N times), then  how much data is typically downloaded ( by Resolve transaction) to a new owner of the asset in a subsequent trade? Say in the above example, till #2, there is no entry in Bank of Baguettes's database. After step #3, SELECT * FROM NODE_TRANSACTIONS shows three rows. So how much data is added to Bank of Baguettes's database as a result of step #3? Is there any general theory on this download size?

Answer (score 0):

Key randomisation is not yet enabled in Milestone 14, but will happen automatically in a future branch.

You can see an example of "tearing off" a transaction in net.corda.core.flows.NotaryFlow.kt. See the line `wtx.buildFilteredTransaction(Predicate { it is StateRef || it is TimeWindow })`. However, we don't currently support tear-offs for transaction resolution.

In the current implementation, each node will download the entire history of each input as part of `ResolveTransactions`. However, in the future, the chain will identify participants using randomised anonymous keys.

Parts of the transaction chain may also have tear-offs or not be fully resolved or not downloaded at all if there is a trusted intermediary who has already verified the chain, but neither feature is implemented yet.

Comment: In future 
1. Does the developer need to generate 'randomised anonymous keys' in a flow and use those keys in appropriate api?
2. OR, The existing API/flow like CollectSignaturesFlow, Send, SendAndReceive etc will do this key generation task on behalf of the developer behind the screen?
3. If we assume that randomised anonymous keys are generate by the developer/framework , how does this scheme ensures that in the above example Bank of Baguettes does not know about the participants/amount of the transaction #2?

Comment: If we assume that transaction privacy is in place by using 'randomised anonymous keys' or other methods, how does this enable auditors to audit asset history?

Answer (score 0):

I think "Confidential Identities" from release-V1 addresses the privacy issue put by Batsayan Das, am I right?

> Confidential identities are key pairs where the corresponding X.509 certificate (and path) are not made public, so that parties who are not involved in the transaction cannot identify its participants.

Reference: https://docs.corda.net/api-identity.html?highlight=anonymous#confidential-identities